# How to draw ticket shape in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I would like to draw the ticket shape in the picture using Path in Jetpack Compose

Path().apply

Help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: you can read my post for detailed answer https://medium.com/p/b987a52c743c

Answer (score 0):

```
class TicketShape(private val cornerRadius: Float) : Shape {

    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        return Outline.Generic(
            // Draw your custom path here
            path = drawTicketPath(size = size, cornerRadius = cornerRadius)
        )
    }
}

fun drawTicketPath(size: Size, cornerRadius: Float): Path {
    return Path().apply {
        reset()
        // Top left arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = -cornerRadius,
                top = -cornerRadius,
                right = cornerRadius,
                bottom = cornerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(x = size.width - cornerRadius, y = 0f)
        // Top right arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = size.width - cornerRadius,
                top = -cornerRadius,
                right = size.width + cornerRadius,
                bottom = cornerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 180.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height - cornerRadius)
        // Bottom right arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = size.width - cornerRadius,
                top = size.height - cornerRadius,
                right = size.width + cornerRadius,
                bottom = size.height + cornerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 270.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(x = cornerRadius, y = size.height)
        // Bottom left arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = -cornerRadius,
                top = size.height - cornerRadius,
                right = cornerRadius,
                bottom = size.height + cornerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 0.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(x = 0f, y = cornerRadius)
        close()
    }
}
```

Now use it with any Composable,

```
MyComp(
  Modifier.clip(
    TicketShape( 24.dp.toPx() )
  )
)
```

Source: https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42

We're basically inheriting from a `Shape` object, which is something the clip modifiers and other shape parameters accept to render the desired shape. Other examples are `RectangleShape`, `CircleShape`, `RoundedCornerShape`, etc, which are pre-built for compose. You need a distinct shape and so, you require to create your own `Shape` object. You didn't exactly need to create the class separately if you don't wish to use it again and again. In that case, an object at the place of usage should have sufficed, but it appears that it is not just a decoration so you might wanna create the class itself to not have to create the same objects at multiple places.

Comment: Hi, it's a really beautiful ticket, it really is. But it doesn't look anything like the image provided. I have tried looking all over the internet, couldn't find anything. Help is greatly appreciated. Couldn't draw it myself either.

Comment: Good heavens, I'm so so sorry. I didn't realise that it wasn't the same image. I guess it was just in the back of my head so I just shared the code here. I'll refactor, don't worry.

Comment: Ok, get me the pathData of the shape using any online drawing tool that converts vectors to svg data, or using Figma (recommended), which has the android vector drawable plugin, converting the vector to the desired android XML pathdata format directly.

Comment: Can I use the XML pathdata in Jetpack compose? I'm trying to draw the path in jetpack compose using the path class and arcTo lineTo and all that good stuff.

Comment: i got this error 
Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option

using compose 1.3.0

Comment: Oh that's a mythic error, sir. It comes and goes. To this say, nobody has been able to correctly point out why this demon spawns in the code out of nowhere. We don't talk about this. It is best that you delete the comment and pretend like the error never appeared. It will become reality in a matter of time. Peace,

Comment: @JohanAlbrectsen did you find an answer? I have to do something really similar